# Какие приемы, решения, технологии я обязан использовать в своем PHP коде?

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Раньше я писал на C# и Delphi. Решил перейти в веб на PHP.
Я регулярно публикую свой код на различных форумах программистов, в сообществах и получаю рекомендации. Имея опыт в других языках, некоторые рекомендации мне кажутся сомнительными.

В связи с этим возник вопрос - какие приемы, решения, технологии я обязан использовать в своем PHP коде? Что обязан, что желательно, а что совсем не обязательно?
Претендую на должность PHP джуна, джуна ++

Вот список:

1. Именование констант, классов...и т.д. согласно PSR
2. Использовать стандарт автозагрузки PSR-4 и композер (+ меппинг неймспейса на директорию)
3. Использовать автоформатирование кода PhpStorm или другой IDE (не форматировать код как тебе удобно)
4. Использовать фреймворки для своих разработок (не писать проект с нуля)
5. Использовать шаблонизатор Blade/Twig, а не самописный (если всё таки пишу проект с нуля)
6. Всегда (именно так советуют) использовать строгую типизацию в PHP
7. Использовать PDO, а не mysqli
8. Использовать подготовленные запросы
9. Руководствоваться паттерном MVC при разработке нового проекта/доработке текущего проекта
10. Использовать тестирование PHPUnit (покрывать код тестами)

PS
Может и вы что то посоветуете.

Comment: 8 - обязательно, всё остальное зависит от задач, их уровня масштабности, уровня проекта, стандартов кодирования в конкретной команде конкретной компании и пр. Т.е. варьиурется. Даже следование PSR может меняться в зависимости от команды к команде. То есть все пункты, кроме 8 - субъективное. Объективно ответить нельзя, но изучить и знать их - неплохо было бы

Comment: 10 тоже прекрасно, считаю. Когда-то писал без тестов (когда только начинал), сейчас вообще не представляю, как это возможно.

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, Andre Polykanine - спасибо за ответы.
На пунктах 1 2 3 6 8 особенно настаивают. То есть пишу PHP код, показываю. Если метод имеет имя в C# стиле - MyMethod, говорят что это характеризует код новичка, пиши my_method. С композером аналогично - подключил классы include_once - нуб. Если код не форматирован как положено, как форматирует IDE - говорят ревьювер смотреть не будет (напоминаю я претендую на джуна и иногда отправляю код рекрутерам ). И, самое новое "требование" - использовать в PHP строгую типизацию - иначе нуб.

Comment: Ну вот, как я и писал, для кого-то важно именно так, а не иначе. Вот например мы в компании пишем имена методов и даже свойств в camelCase (не путать с PascalCase) , а вариант underscore_case считаем устаревшим

Comment: Если проект - сайт-визитка, то композер не нужен, а подключение через include - вполне допустим (мой сайт-визитка именно так сделан, хотя в большом проекте на работе естественно используем автозагрузку и композер) .... Так что **всё зависит, как я писал, от целей задач и масштабов**..... А вот абсолютно всюду пихать все указаные правила - глупо и, как раз, удел нубов 